# how to Secure php data receiving sub-directories

Tags: php, html, lamp

I have LAMP server installed and working correctly. I am using PHP to "read" data sent from "user" and "save" it to a "sub-directory". But the problem is that "sub-directory" is visible to anyone who enters the correct URL. I am very new to php, can anyone suggest me that how can I make these "data directories" secure/hidden? What would be the piece of codes to add, and where? Or should I just change these "sub-directories" to be out of php? I dont want these to be visible from URLs.

Comment: `.htaccess` should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move outside of you webdir. If they are not required to be there.

If you cant move them. You can use .htaccess to block access.

Comment: ok, so instead of saving it in `/var/www/html/dir1` I should move to some where else?

Comment: yes. A simple place to put is /opt/YOURAPPNAME/ Then make sure the userid the web server is running under has read write access.

Comment: Thank you, let me try this.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a .htaccess file in the secure/hidden folder and write this in the .htaccess

```
Deny from all
```

But as other suggested it would be best if you move the folder outside of your webdir.